# Move Sprite on Y-axis by dragging screen

Tags: iphone, sprite, sprite-kit

How do I make a sprite in sprite kit move up and down on the y axis (iPhone is in landscape). The sprite has to stay on a set X value. This is done when the user drags it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement **touchesMoved**

Subtract the the current location from previous location of the receiver and you will get the amount to move your sprite.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint scenePosition = [touch locationInNode:self];
  CGPoint lastPosition = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];

  CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(0.0, scenePosition.y - lastPosition.y);
  yourSprite.position = CGPointMake(yourSprite.position.x, yourSprite.position.y + translation.y); 
}
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in touches {
    let scenePosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let lastPosition = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

    let translation = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: scenePosition.y - lastPosition.y)
    yourSprite.position = CGPointMake(yourSprite.position.x, yourSprite.position.y + translation.y);
  }
}
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution for absolute positioning:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    }
    CGPoint spriteLocation = yourSprite.position; 
    spriteLocation.y = touchLocation.y;
    yourSprite.position = spriteLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this method of SKAction class:-

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{

```
   [mySprite runAction:[SKAction moveToY:400 duration:0.2];
```

}

This SKAction Method creates an action that moves a node vertically.